# Form with a checked checkbox works, without - doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

One controller:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    flat = Flat.find(params[:flat_id])
    @flat = FlatDecorator.new(flat)

    @product = flat.products.new(product_params)
    if @product.save
      redirect_to flat
    else
      render 'flats/show'
    end
  end

  private

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit([:name, :flatmate_id, :present, :flat_id])
    end

end
```

Another controller:

```
class FlatmatesController < ApplicationController

  def create
    flat = Flat.find(params[:flat_id])
    @flat = FlatDecorator.new(flat)

    @flatmate = flat.flatmates.new(flatmate_params)
    if @flatmate.save
      redirect_to flat
    else
      render 'flats/show'
    end
  end

  private

  def flatmate_params
    params.require(:flatmate).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

And the view:

```
<h2>Flat <%= @flat.name%></h2>

<div>
<h3>Products</h3>
<ol>
  <% @flat.products.each do |product| %>
    <% if product.persisted? %>
      <li><%= product.name %> <%= product.present %></li>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ol>
</div>
<div>
  <%= form_for [@flat, @product] do |form|%>
      <p>
        <%= form.label :name %>
        <%= form.text_field :name %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= form.label :flatmate_id, "Who buys next" %>
        <%= collection_select :product, :flatmate_id, @flat.flatmates, :id, :name %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= form.label :present %>
        <%= form.check_box :present %>
      </p>
      <p>
        <%= form.submit %>
      </p>
  <% end %>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>Flatmates</h3>
  <ol>
    <% @flat.flatmates.each do |flatmate| %>
      <% if flatmate.persisted? %>
        <li><%= flatmate.name %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
</div>

<div>
  <%= form_for [@flat, @flatmate] do |form|%>
    <p>
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </p>
    <p>
      <%= form.submit %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

When trying to submit the first form (Products) with the checkbox unchecked, I get

```
First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty
```

on the `form_for` from the second form. When debuged, the `@flatmate` is then `nil` and `@flat` is alright.

When the checkbox is checked, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you building `form_for` for `@flat` or `@flatmate`? and your view belongs to which `action` in which `controller`?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `render` in Rails, it is not actually calling the named method, just rendering it's view. Which means that the instance variables it uses (@flat, @flatmate, @product etc.) are not being set anywhere, so are instead being interpreted as nil.

When you reach a render call you need to ensure that all the instance variables used by the view are being defined.

Note: It looks like like you're using "flats/show" as your form for changing related objects. This is unusual in rails, I would suggest using nested routes and putting flatmates, products etc under flat. Then moving this to a flat-specific edit form for a collection of these things

```
resources :flats do

  resources :flatmates do
    collection do
      get :edit
      post :update
    end
  end

end
```